# Does this way to prove that the integral of a strictly positive function is positive work?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

I am proving that for Riemann integration $\int^b_af(x)dx=\int^b_a\frac{dF}{dx}dx=F(b)-F(a)<0$ which implies that $F(b) < F(a)$. Then by proof of contradiction we get that since:

$\frac{F(b)-F(a)}{b-a} > 0$ and we assume b>a then F(b) > F(a), which is thus a contradiction so F(b) - F(a) will always be positive.

Does this work?

Also, I am trying to prove that the integral of $f(x)^2$ is zero, if and only if $f(x)^2$ is zero, But then we can use the same reasoning:
One way holds definetly, the integral of zero is just zero. The other side:

Assume that F(b) - F(a) = 0 and f $\neq$ 0.  Then F(b) = F(a) and then $\frac{F(b)-F(a)}{b-a}=0$, so that applies f is also zero.
Does this work?

Comment: I’m not sure what you are trying to achieve with the first half of the question. For the second half, you are assuming that $f^2$ has an antiderivative, which is not true for general Riemann integrable functions. It is better to consider the upper/lower sum and use non-negativity of squares.

Comment: How do you know $[F(b)-F(a)]/(b-a) > 0$?

Comment: @eyeballfrog because f = $\frac{F(x)}{dx} > 0$

Comment: @Mysterium I am trying to prove that $\int^b_a f(x)g(x) dx$ is an inner product. Wouldn't it be logical to assume it has an anti-derivative already?

Comment: @Lisastronomy In that case I take it you're working in $L^2$, and thus $f(x)^2$ is already assumed to be integrable.

Comment: @eyeballfrog Alright, thank you! Then this method works right?